# Omniauth route issue related to ruby version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, omniauth

I have create a rails engine that uses omniauth. In that engine, regardless of running on ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.2, when I test it using the dummy application, everything works just as fine (using Rails 3.1.3).

I can login using any of the providers by going to `/auth/:provider`, such as `/auth/google`.

When I include (as a gem) that engine and mount it to `'/'` in the host application, the login process works when I use ruby 1.8.7, but gives me a `No route matches [GET] "/auth/google` when I use ruby 1.9.2.

So, to wrap it up, I get a `No route matches [GET] "/auth/google` when Omniauth is inside an engine and that I use Ruby 1.9.2.

I tried the devise solution where you create a pass thru action that generates a 404 error, but if I do that, I then get stuck on that 404 error...

Any ideas?

Comment: This issue is relly bound to the ruby version. Whenever I switch back to 1.8.7 using rvm, it works, and then switch to 1.9.2, and I get the error. What is really weird is that this always works in the dummy application where the gem is also mounted on `'/'`.

Comment: I also having this problem. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

write the following code in your Engine

```rb
middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :provider, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET' 
end
```

and you will have login url under /mount_point/auth/:provider

Comment: Your answer helped me in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/15420925/347501 thanks!